# Verificar se int é "null" em C#

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, null, int

No C# não é possível atribuir `null` a um valor inteiro (`int`, não `int?`).

No entanto, como eu posso saber se um valor inteiro (`int`) ainda não teve um valor atribuído (sendo do tipo `int`)?

```
int? valor;
if (valor == null)
{
   // Isso pode
}
```

Porém..

```
int valor;
if (valor == null)
{
   // Isso não
}
```

Como verificar se um inteiro ainda não recebeu nenhum valor?

Comment: Transformar em `String` e depois verificar o conteúdo com o método `equals()` não poderia ser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um tipo por valor sempre terá atribuído um valor. Declarou a variável e ela entrou no escopo tem um valor. Se o código não definir nenhum será a adotado o valor padrão que é 0.

Se precisa definir se uma variável tinha um valor e depois passou ou não ter outro, tem que controlar isso separadamente em outra variável: ou dizendo se teve alteração de valor; ou qual era o valor original para ver se ele ainda é igual, o que dá uma semântica um pouco diferente.

Quando uma variável vale 1 e você atribui um valor 1 nela você mudou o valor da variável, mas o resultado dá o mesmo, só não se engane que tem outro objeto ali, mas que tem o mesmo conteúdo. Se quer saber apenas se o valor é diferente ter o valor anterior parece o mais adequado. Se quer saber se foi atribuído um valor novo para a variável, mas não importa se ele foi mudado, aí uma *flag* é mais útil. O `int?` tem uma *flag*, em alguns casos pode ser suficiente, desde que não deixe o valor ser nulo depois.

Pode criar um tipo para controlar isso, mas pela descrição não pode fazer isto neste caso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Em C#, um `int` não pode ser nulo, caso você precise que ele seja nulo você terá que declara-lo como `Nullable<int>` ou no seu sugar syntax `int?`.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta, porém no caso eu não posso usar "int?" pois estou implementando uma interface que definiu o valor como int, porém em determinados casos ocorre do valor int ainda não ter recebido nenhum valor. Eu precisaria fazer uma verificação e gostaria de saber se isso é possível.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri nesse caso, provavelmente vai dá erro de de utilizar uma variável que não foi inicializada ou dependendo de como esteja vindo esse valor, possa ser que ele pegue seu valor default, que no caso é 0.

Comment: Se o design da interface prevê um int, null não seria um erro? Ou você está querendo retornar o que não deve ou a interface foi mal projetada. Reveja o objetivo da implementação e, se for o caso, faça o tratamento de erro adequado.

Answer (score 1):

No caso você pode usar o "HasValue"

```
    int? valor;
   if (valor.HasValue)
    { 
      int valorDaVariavelValor = valor.value;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Cara, para mim o jeito mais pilantra que existe é converter para string, usar um any()
e também um arrow function.
tipo valorinteiro.tostring().Any() ? "Não é nulo" : "é nulo"